# move image following finger with fix x,y iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How I can move image with fix x,y coordinate smooth (following user finger) in **xcode 5**.
I have make some code but it doesn't move following my finger gesture (image move instantly to new location)
here my `.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyScene.h"

@interface ViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeGestureRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeGestureRecognizer;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)HandlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
self.rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];

self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
self.rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.rightSwipeGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)handleSwipes:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
{
    CGPoint labelPosition = CGPointMake(self.pesawat.frame.origin.x - 30.0, self.pesawat.frame.origin.y);
    self.pesawat.frame = CGRectMake( labelPosition.x , labelPosition.y , self.pesawat.frame.size.width, self.pesawat.frame.size.height);
 }

if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
{
    CGPoint labelPosition = CGPointMake(self.pesawat.frame.origin.x + 30.0, self.pesawat.frame.origin.y);
 self.pesawat.frame = CGRectMake( labelPosition.x , labelPosition.y , self.pesawat.frame.size.width, self.pesawat.frame.size.height);
}
}
```

and here my `.h`

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *pesawat;
    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to maintain the y position, change the x

```
basketView.center = CGPointMake(point.x, basketView.center.y);
```

Or I recommend you to follow these tutorials:

**1)** http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/04/17/iphone-drawing-on-screen-follow-a-finger/

**2)** http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites

Hopefully this info will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As a very basic example,

You should use a panGestureRecognizer:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
[panner addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panner];
```

Then:

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner {

    CGPoint translation = [panner translationInView:panner.view];
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.pesawat.center.x + translation.x, self.pesawat.center.y);

    int offset = 30; // pixels to offset

    if (newCenter.x < offset) newCenter = CGPointMake(offset, newCenter.y);
    else if (newCenter.x > self.view.bounds.size.width - offset) newCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - offset, newCenter.y);

    self.pesawat.center = newCenter;
    [panner setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:panner.view];
}
```

Comment: where i should put first code? because it's not recognize my image variable

Comment: my image just move following my finger, what i want is moving image in fix coordinate as my code, but with smoothly

Comment: Your question: "I have make some code but it doesn't move following my finger gesture." Now it does?  What behavior do you want?

Comment: sorry i'm not explain clearly, behavior i want is my image move 30 point to left or right(move just horizontal/vertical,not dragable. my code above can move object with fix 30 point to left/right, but it's move instantly to new location(not move according to my finger gesture).what i want is the image should move following my finger,its same as f you slide in home screen,the icons move following finger) nb:the gesture should recognize an entire screen. sorry for my english if it's not explain clearly to you

Comment: Is this more what you're looking for? (see update).  You'll need to update the offset to whatever pixel distance you'd like your view to adhere.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with a Long Press Gesture recognizer.  Like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *ges = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(lp:)];
ges.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;
self.pesawat.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.pesawat addGestureRecognizer:ges];
```

Then add this:

```
-(void)lp:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)ges{
    float x = ([ges locationInView:self.GraphicBox].x);
    float y = ([ges locationInView:self.GraphicBox].y);
    [imgView setCenter:CGPointMake(x,y)];
}
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Sorry man, I accidentally edited this, I clicked on the wrong answer.  Just ignore.

Comment: sorry but what for that GraphicBox? cause xcode not recognize that